# Chromwebdriver problen when installing appium

Tags: android, ubuntu, installation, appium, chrome-web-driver

I´m installing appium using these terminal commands:

sudo npm install -g appium

npm install wd

the installation process never ends and the error is :

Error trying to install Chromedriver binary. Waiting and trying again. fn must be a function

i tried to install Chromedriver manually but i still have the same problem, i also tried to do this on a vagrant machine and i still have the same issue and i don't know how to solve this,

if anyone has an answer it will be nice to share

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not install nodejs through apt-get, which will need sudo rights and appium will not work if node is installed as sudo user. If you have already installed remove it using

```
      sudo apt-get remove nodejs
      sudo apt-get remove npm
```

Download latest nodejs linux binaries form http://nodejs.org/download/

Extract into a folder that doesn't need sudo rights to access, for example your home folder.

tar -xvf

Add the following line to your ~/.bashrc file.

```
  export PATH=$PATH:<full_path_of_the_extracted_node_folder>/bin
```

Open a now terminal and do

```
  npm install -g appium
  appium
```